# how to check what happend to reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

My SO rep reduced from 1023 to 1019. **I checked in the profile page reputation tab** and there was no record of how it happened.(*this happened 11-07-2012 or maybe 12-07-2012*) 
Last time I did in SO was deleting an answer with no points(*no up-vote or down-vote*). As I know deleting an answer that has no points don't make any changes to rep.

**EDIT**

 last record of reputation change is on **07-07-2012**

after I went to https://stackoverflow.com/reputation as @Somnath Muluk says

found this

> 16 11130975 (2)
>    16 11133716 (2)
>    16 11141158 (2)
>   -- 2012-06-22 rep +6    = 1019
>   -- 2012-06-26 rep 0     = 1019
>   -- 2012-07-06 rep 0     = 1019
>   -- 2012-07-11 rep 0     = 1019
>    3  11114262 (-2)
>   -- 2012-07-12 rep -2    = 1017

but **I really had 1023 rep** if I'm not blind. This records don't show it at all.

any idea?

Comment: `As I know deleting an answer that has no points don't make any changes to rep.` That's only true if there are ***no*** votes on it. If the ***net*** votes is zero, there will be a rep change. Scroll down to the bottom of your reputation tab and check the "show removed posts" box.

Comment: @Mysticial I already check that.

Comment: @DR There are a couple deleted posts that'd affect your reputation. Have you tried checking the "show removed posts" checkbox on the Reputation tab of your profile?

Comment: @AnnaLear yes, there are no record of **11-07-2012 or 12-07-2012**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by comparing

> 16 11130975 (2)
>    16 11133716 (2)
>    16 11141158 (2)
>   -- 2012-06-22 rep +6    = 1019
>   -- 2012-06-26 rep 0     = 1019
>   -- 2012-07-06 rep 0     = 1019
>   -- 2012-07-11 rep 0     = 1019
>    3  11114262 (-2)
>   -- 2012-07-12 rep -2    = 1017

and

[image: rep tab in SO profile]

I can think of that changes were applied lately somehow. **changes on 2012-06-23, 2012-07-03 and 2012-07-07 were applied 2012-07-11 or 2012-07-12** and it's even didn't recorded in https://stackoverflow.com/reputation.

Answer (score 4):

Click check-box checked [rep tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1244383/d-r?tab=reputation) at bottom. And see any removed posts.

[image]

You can also check all rep here https://stackoverflow.com/reputation. See if any changes are there.

Comment: those links are for MSO but I have problem in SO

Comment: @DR - links are now to SO.