# Why did my reputation just change without activities?

Tags: support, reputation, recent-activity

More or less one hour ago I had 2475 reputation. Now I find I have 2495, but I have no notifications on reputation tab in my profile.

It's good, but why did it happen? Maybe for recent changes in rep calculation system (now always recalculating from real activities)?

Comment: It is possible that someone who regularly downvoted you got their account deleted. There is a checkmark on the reputation page (towards the bottom) - "show removed posts". Tick it and see if that's the case.

Comment: Or an answer that was deleted got undeleted.

Comment: @ChrisF - I thought that undeleted items show up even without the tick? And that they do show up on the rep list for the day the change occurred?

Comment: @Oded - I'm not sure. I think the votes will show up back on the day they originally occurred.

Comment: @ChrisF - I believe there was a change a few months ago to make such occurrences more visible.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139449/178505.